# Issue with Password Reset Flow for Blazor with Azure AD B2C

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

We have a Blazor WebAssembly app running on .NET Core 3.1 and using Azure B2C Authentication Flows.

Login flows work just find.

We now need to implement the Password Reset Flow.
The defaults were not working so we followed this guide for a workaround.

https://iheartms.azurewebsites.net/2020/04/10/blazor-aad-b2c-additional-user-flows/?fbclid=IwAR0LQn1zeXPY5JIpezJkMtdzmQSkP38PkFzGeFeUM72-pSD1-rvTsR0BWOE

It worked for the most part, we are able to reset the password, however, when the flow navigates back to the Blazor App with the token, the passwordreset-callback page is displayed but not redirecting to the main page,
we even tried to override all of the methods in the page component to check if any is executing, but none is.

We need a way to fix this, so the users can login after resetting the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The password reset flow was just updated in AzureADB2c, please refer to the updated docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#self-service-password-reset-recommended

They have removed the need to trap and handle an error code on the client - as it is all handled by AzureADB2C.